# Is there a way in OBIEE,to provide the prompt functionality in excel as in dashboard when we run the dashboard

Tags: obiee

In obiee 12c, i create a dashboard with a prompt and two analysis.When i export the dashboard in excel, it provide the static view of prompt.I am just curious , is there any way to provide the prompt functionality to the end user ? For me it seems impossible.

Comment: Did you give up on this?

Answer (score 1):

Smartview allows you more interaction with your data inside Excel. But you can't expect dashboards to work like they do in OBI in Excel  when you download them.

Comment: if end user is not able to enable the Smartview in excel. Is there any other way to provide the functionality to the end user.

Comment: Yes: Use the product and don't try to force it into Excel. The tool is there for a reason. You also wouldn't try to view a movie in Notepad.